# Rails - What does the instance :topic mean in this line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

Where it says :topic, what is that doing? From what I can understand :topic could also be :posts if that is your model. But why is it specified there exactly? Thanks

```
 def favorable(opts={})

  # favorable_type
  type = opts[:type] ? opts[:type] : :topic  
  type = type.to_s.capitalize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:topic` is a symbol, which is basically a string. So, if there's no `:type` key in the `opts` hash, `type = "Topic"`.

I suppose they're using `:topic` instead of `"Topic"` because the `opts[:type]` would return a symbol, maybe `:whatever` and they want to set type to `"Whatever"`.